# Decoding a polyline in android

Tags: android, polyline

I want to check whether a new polyline A draw on google map touches or overlaps to any of the previously drawn polylines( B, C, D...). During searching a solution I got an algorithm as follows

```
  Polyline findExistingPolyline(Polyline[] polylines, Polyline polyline) {
  LatLng[] polylinePoints = PolylineDecoder.toLatLng(polyline);
  for (Polyline existing: polylines) {
     LatLng[] existingPoints = PolylineDecoder.toLatLng(existing);
     if (isMostlyCovered(existingPoints , polylinePoints)) {
        return existing;
     }
   }

   return null;

  }

   boolean isMostlyCovered(LatLng[] existingPoints, LatLng[] polylinePoints) {
   int initialSize = polylinePoints.length;
   for (LatLng point: polylinePoints) {
     for (LatLng existingPoint: existingPoints) {
        if (distanceBetween(existingPoint, point) <= 100) {
          polylinePoints.remove();// I actually use iterator, here it is just demosnstration
        }
     }
   }
   // check how many points are left and decide if polyline is mostly covered
   // if 90% of the points is removed - existing polylines covers new polyline
   return (polylinePoints.length * 100 / initialSize) <= 10;
  }
```

In this algorithm a class PolylineDecoder passing a polyline to its method used, later I found this class at multiple links but almost at every place it is receiving a string not a polyline

```
public class PolylineDecoder {


public static ArrayList decodePoly(String encoded) {
  ArrayList poly = new ArrayList();
  int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
  int lat = 0, lng = 0;
  while (index < len) {
   int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
   do {
    b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
    result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
    shift += 5;
   } while (b >= 0x20);
   int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
   lat += dlat;
   shift = 0;
   result = 0;
   do {
    b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
    result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
    shift += 5;
   } while (b >= 0x20);
   int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
   lng += dlng;
   Location p = new Location((((double) lat / 1E5)),
     (((double) lng / 1E5)));
   poly.add(p);
  }
  return poly;
 }
}
```

so what I did convert the polyline into string and passed it to the PolylineDecoder class

```
LatLng[] polylinePoints = PolylineDecoder.toLatLng(polyline.toString());
```

Now when I run the program it gives exception(string out of bound exception) in PolylineDecoder class for the second do while loop at line

```
b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
```

how can I handle this exception or did I miss some intermediate step? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We should unescape any Java literals found in the String poly line. It can be done using

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(polyline)
```

The above can be changed into

```
polyline  = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(polyline.toString());
LatLng[] polylinePoints = PolylineDecoder.toLatLng(polyline);
```